# When using Generics types, how can I call an Attribute of an inherited class on the Base class instance with Python / Django?

Tags: python, django, object, oop

Let's say I have a base Generic class called person to group all other persons that extend it:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

And the class Worker, that extends the Person:

```
class Worker(Person):
    card_id = models.CharField(...)
```

When I access all Person objects I also see the Workers, but lets say that from there I want to do this:

```
worker = Worker(name='Example', card_id='1234')

person = Person.objects.all().first()
```

**Let's say that for some reason I want to use the Person class and call an Attribute o Worker:**

```
[in] person.card_id
# Somehow expecting this result:
[out] '1234
```

**Is it possible, is it viable and how do I do it?**

Comment: That depends on whether `person` refers to an instance of `Worker` or not, which you can't assume based simply on the output of `Person.objects.all()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible, even when you can guarantee that the `Person` object you retrieved (ie. `Person.objects.all().first()`) is also a `Worker`.

There three styles of inheritance possible in Django: [Abstract Base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes), [Proxy Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models), and [Multi-Table Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

In this case, you are using [Multi-Table Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). As the name suggest, each model will receive its own table in the database and can therefore also be queried.

When querying for `Person` objects, what you will end up with are `Person` instances, not `Worker` instances or any other child class instance. Since the `card_id` field is not defined in the `Person` model, but rather in one of its child models, you will get an error when trying to retrieve the `card_id` value of `Person` instance, even though the instance is also a `Worker`.

However, if you know that your `Person` instance is also a `Worker`, you can retrieve it via:

```
person = Person.objects.all().first()
worker = person.worker
```

This works because the inheritance relationship creates a `OneToOneField` between the child and each of its parents. However, note that this will give an error in case the `person` instance is not actually a `Worker`.

One library that might help is the [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) from `django-model-utils`.

By attaching the InheritanceManager to your base class model such as:

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Person(models.Model):
    objects = InheritanceManager()
    # ...
```

You can then use the `.select_subclasses` filter to filter a queryset of the Parent model to only include the objects of a particular child class. For example to only select the persons that are also workers, you can do the following query:

```
persons_worker = Person.objects.select_subclasses(Worker)
```

and you should never run into troubles when trying to do retrieve the `card_id` for any of the instances in `persons_worker`.